# Instagram API Tag Endpoint only retrieving public photos, not private friends I am following

Tags: c#, instagram

I am using the instagram API through the c# library, instasharp.

I have authenticated correctly (as I am able to do the self feed api call to retrieve my own private photos).

I am doing a search by a tag, however it not returning private users that I am following, which I can see in the instagram phone app.

My understanding was that the point of authenticating with the api was to see images relating to the authenticated user, including friends I am following.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try emailing support. I had a similar issue when trying to retrieve likes from users i am following and it was a bug in their API. Also if you could show us which endpoint you are using i could give it a try.